# Access to generated classes in annotation processing

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-databinding

I'm writing `Annotation processor`that uses Android DataBinding that looks like this:

```
public @interface Bind{
    int brID();
}
```

And use it like this:

```
@Bind(brID = BR.someBind)
class Test{
    // Some code
}
```

All seems OK, but when I try to access `brID` value in annotation processor it gives `AnnotationTypeMismatchException` that says that `int` can't be cast to `BR` despite I specified `BR.someBind` that is `int`.

I know that `BR` class is generated during build process, so I assume that my processor happens to process when `BR` constants is not generated and there is only `BR` class present.

For now I'm accessing value via reflection. I specify `"someBind"` value and create class `BRFinder` in default location of `BR` class and then access that class field with name "someBind" and return it `int` value. But this is not really best solution because of: a) Location of `BR` class can change, b) Field names can be changed due to obfuscation, c) Reflection is not really quick thing.

So my question is: how can I access values that are generated during build?

Comment: is ***someBind*** a constant?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Basically yes. `DataBinding` generates BR class with constants (`public static final int` fields) that can be used. And "someBind" is `BR.someBind`

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ But number behind this constant may change. For example if you have 3 binding fields, BR will have 3 constants for you with values (for example): 1 for `BR.bind1`,2 for `BR.bind2`,3 for `BR.bind3`. And then if you delete `BR.bind1` all next values will be decremente. So you can't just always assume that BR.someBind will always have same value.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, since the BR ID's change regularly, it may be better to reference the `BR.property` in your generated code, rather than directly inserting the referenced value.

A possibility would be to modify your annotation to be:

```
public @interface Bind {
    /**
     * BR Class.
     */
    Class br();

    /**
     * BR Class Property.
    String property();
}
```

And your usage to be:

```
@Bind(br = BR.class, property = "someBind")
class Test{
    // Some code
}
```

Then, in your annotation processor, generate code that accesses the property on the supplied BR class.